# I flagged an answer as spam, where the user profile contained spam. Why was my flag declined?

Tags: support, flagging, spam, user-profiles

My "spam" flag on https://superuser.com/a/1834925/1482432 was declined. Did the moderator not see the username and the profile of the spambot?

"*Declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it*"

The comment was "doesn't work because the way I replaced VarSetCapacity(monitorInfo, 40) doesn't seem to be what the DllCall expects." (a spambotty rehash of what was already on the page).

But the username was Okkabeautydubai

and the profile contained "Online Shopping Site for Fashion & Lifestyle. We brings you a variety of Clothing, Accessories, Makeup products, Skin Care Products and lifestyle products for women. Okkabeauty is the best Online Fashion Store."

Comment: You should have customer flagged it as profile spam

Comment: @DavidPostill How do I do that? Perhaps the moderator should spent 2 more seconds before declining a flag.

Comment: Flag > "In need of moderator intervention" and explain why in the text box.

Comment: @DavidPostill Ah lol "customer" = custom I get it now. Yeah I thought it was obvious but apparently not. Weird that we can't flag a profile.

Comment: The answer is cr@p but it is not spam.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes it is. Of course it is.

Comment: Anyway user has been nuked.

Comment: @DavidPostill And nothing of value was lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DavidPostill nuked the spambot.